# I have a 100a service and 200a main and meter base. With 200 amp cord

Tags: electrical

Would it be safe to use the combination until I can afford to change it all out at once?

Comment: What is the 200A "cord"? Are you referring to the service cable coming from the utility's connection to your house?

Comment: The safety of a lower-amp service and higher-amp equipment is determined by the main circuit breaker. A 100A main breaker on a 100A service is OK despite the higher-amp equipment. A 200A main breaker on 100A service is not safe. (Just found that out $2000 ago in my house....) What's your main breaker size?

Comment: How about pictures of the labels of all the devices in question. That way, the folks here, (some of whom are actually electricians) will be able to cast a knowledgeable eye over the actual details instead of guessing at what you mean.

Comment: I have a 200a main breaker for the emergency shut off

Comment: My cables from the meter box to the 100a service inside the cabin is 200 amp

Answer (score 2):

If you have a 100A service, then if you follow the wires from where the service enters your house, the first breaker you encounter must be 100A or less. This is to avoid overloading your service feed.

Everything after that can be rated for 200A without any problem. You won't be able to use the full 200A capacity, but you would be all set for a future upgrade of the service to 200A.

Comment: So. I can have a 200a main emergency shut with my 100a service?

Comment: My cables from the meter box to the 100a service inside the cabin is 200 amp

Answer (score 1):

If by "cord" you mean the feeder, and the first breaker it hits is 200A, you have 200A service.

If the feeder isn't rated for 200A, but is wired from a pole rather than underground, and the wire on your house from the feeder to your main breaker *is* rated for 200A...

I am told that it is possible (though not ideal) to safely draw 200A through an overhead feeder intended for 100A. It will heat up more than it should, but in free air it will radiate enough of that heat to not be an immediate problem. My electricians did that when I upgraded to 200A; replacing  the feeder is the utility company's job, and they had a year-long backlog so they approved this cheat.

***IF*** that's your situation, the 200A main/cutoff breaker makes some sense and you actually have (semi-bootleg) 200A of usable service even if you aren't drawing that much.

Otherwise... what you've describing confuses/worries me.

Comment: Yes it is over head and everything is 200 amp except the service is 100 amp

Comment: The feeder is over head then runs underground to inside the house

Comment: The underground run is the limiting factor, I think. If that's only rated for 100A, your first breaker should be 100, not 200, to protect it. But the inspector should have caught that if so. You might consider calling the electric company, though if you're right about the problem they may make you replace that 200A breaker. (I am assuming that by cut-off you mean breaker. If it's just a cut-off switch -- I'm not sure if that's allowed before the breaker or not -- it can be over-rated without being a problem.)